# Save IPython.core.display.Image object

Tags: python, image

I have a file of format `<IPython.core.display.Image object>` which I receive like this:

```
graph = uplift_tree_plot (uplift_model.fitted_uplift_tree, x_names)
img = Image (graph.create_png ())
```

How can I save this png image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using [`causalml`](https://github.com/uber/causalml) to generate `graph`, so by inspecting the source to `uplift_tree_plot()`, we can see that it returns an object of some class provided by the `pydotplus` package:

```py
def uplift_tree_plot(decisionTree, x_names):
    '''
    Convert the tree to dot graph for plots.
    Args
    ----
    decisionTree : object
        object of DecisionTree class
    x_names : list
        List of feature names
    Returns
    -------
    Dot class representing the tree graph.
    '''
    ...
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
    return graph
```

The `pydotplus` API documentation is not very helpful to understand what that object can do either, so we can also [inspect its source](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/pydotplus/blob/master/lib/pydotplus/graphviz.py#L1770) to understand  what the API provides. This turns out to be written in a way that's hard to search for the function we care about because it generates some of them dynamically, but `Dot.__init__` sets up functions to render images in various formats, delegating to `Dot.create` to do the actual rendering when you call `create_png`. That function at least has some documentation:

```py
    def create(self, prog=None, format='ps'):
        """Creates and returns a Postscript representation of the graph.
        create will write the graph to a temporary dot file and process
        it with the program given by 'prog' (which defaults to 'twopi'),
        reading the Postscript output and returning it as a string is the
        operation is successful.
        On failure None is returned.
        There's also the preferred possibility of using:
            create_'format'(prog='program')
        which are automatically defined for all the supported formats.
        [create_ps(), create_gif(), create_dia(), ...]
        If 'prog' is a list instead of a string the fist item is expected
        to be the program name, followed by any optional command-line
        arguments for it:
            ['twopi', '-Tdot', '-s10']
        """
```

So because this function returns the contents of the rendered file, you could simply `write` the returned bytestring to a file of your choosing. However the `Dot` class also provides a `write` family of methods that writes to a specified file rather than to a temporary file that it then reads back, so you could more simply call `graph.write_png('my_graph.png')`.